# Wordpress the_excerpt not returning content from the Excerpt field

Tags: wordpress

The problem I'm having is that the_excerpt() isn't returning the content from the post's "Excerpt" field.  Instead, it's returning the first part of the post, as though the "Excerpt" field was empty.

My code is very simple - inside the loop, I have ...

```
if(has_excerpt()) {
  the_excerpt();
} else {
  the_content();
}
```

Is there something that needs to be done to tell wordpress to use the "Excerpt" field.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try this `<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo $excerpt; ?>` Maybe your theme changed the `the_excerpt()` function.

Comment: thanks - yes i've tried that and it returns the same thing as the_excerpt()

Comment: Excuse me, what's the excerpt filed? Is it a custom meta you have in your theme?

Comment: @LoaiNagati , it's a core WordPress function / field.

Comment: "Excerpt" is a field on the admin page where you edit a post.  What I've read in the wp doc is that the_excerpt() will show that content if it exists, otherwise it will show the first 50 words from the post.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this as follows ..

I discovered that the excerpt is stored in the WP_Post class field post_excerpt, so I got it directly with ...

```
$the_post = get_post();
$post_excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $the_post->post_excerpt);
echo $post_excerpt;
```

I would be happy to hear from anyone if there is a better way, and also why the_excerpt() doesn't give that field content.

Thanks for your replies